# Invoking Bean method from Camel without binding/handling exchange

Tags: java, binding, apache-camel, javabeans, interception

Is it possible to use a bean that is not bound to any exchange and just triggers some kind of service start method in the middle of a Camel interception?

```
interceptFrom("a").bean(service, "method")
```

with method looking like

```
public void method() {
  //just do something that has nothing to do with the exchange
}
```

For Camel 2.12.2

Exceptions I get are:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.util.function.Function but has value: ...
```

And another in the same Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: ... to the required type: java.util.function.Function with value ...
```

Comment: I think you could have tested this faster than it took you to type this question.

Comment: I tested this with an interception and it broke everything. actually the interception should be part of the question

Comment: "it broke everything" - what does that mean?

Comment: it gaves errors suggesting the bean required a method accepting an exchange

Comment: What was the exact exception? Can you edit the question with the stack trace?

Comment: TypeConversion fails

Answer (score 0):

I could probably do this with InOnly pattern, but am still not sure.